# login example using jsp and servlet along with mysql

Tags: mysql, jsp, servlets

I have a login example working already which has one sql table . This is my user table which gets the general information about the user. Now i want to insert another table in my database - details , and then connect these two together.
i already created a different POJO class for my details table along with the one i already had for the user table.

```
package com.shreya.dao;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import com.shreya.model.User;
import com.shreya.util.DbUtil;

public class UserDao {

private Connection connection;

public UserDao() {
    connection = DbUtil.getConnection();
}

public void addUser(User user) {
    try {
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection
                .prepareStatement("insert into     users(firstname,lastname,dob,email)       values (?, ?, ?, ? )");
        // Parameters start with 1
        preparedStatement.setString(1, user.getFirstName());
        preparedStatement.setString(2, user.getLastName());
        preparedStatement.setDate(3, new java.sql.Date(user.getDob().getTime()));
        preparedStatement.setString(4, user.getEmail());
        preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void deleteUser(int userId) {
    try {
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection
                .prepareStatement("delete from users where userid=?");
        // Parameters start with 1
        preparedStatement.setInt(1, userId);
        preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void updateUser(User user) {
    try {
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection
                .prepareStatement("update users set firstname=?, lastname=?, dob=?, email=?" +
                        "where userid=?");
        // Parameters start with 1
        preparedStatement.setString(1, user.getFirstName());
        preparedStatement.setString(2, user.getLastName());
        preparedStatement.setDate(3, new java.sql.Date(user.getDob().getTime()));
        preparedStatement.setString(4, user.getEmail());
        preparedStatement.setInt(5, user.getUserid());
        preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public List<User> getAllUsers() {
    List<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();
    try {
        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("select * from users");
        while (rs.next()) {
            User user = new User();
            user.setUserid(rs.getInt("userid"));
            user.setFirstName(rs.getString("firstname"));
            user.setLastName(rs.getString("lastname"));
            user.setDob(rs.getDate("dob"));
            user.setEmail(rs.getString("email"));
            users.add(user);
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return users;
}

public User getUserById(int userId) {
    User user = new User();
    try {
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.
                prepareStatement("select * from users where userid=?");
        preparedStatement.setInt(1, userId);
        ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

        if (rs.next()) {
            user.setUserid(rs.getInt("userid"));
            user.setFirstName(rs.getString("firstname"));
            user.setLastName(rs.getString("lastname"));
            user.setDob(rs.getDate("dob"));
            user.setEmail(rs.getString("email"));
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return user;
}
```

}

this is the one i wrote for the connectivity.
i tried adding the same stuff for the details table . but its just not working .
help would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by **not working** ? if you are getting any exception or error message, update your question with it.

Comment: post the error or any log file.

Comment: got the connectivity thing working . the problem lies with the servlet

Comment: when i try to incorporate the second table along with the previous one , it gives me errors

Comment: if you there, could pls paste the stack trace...